# Using PrimeFaces for conditional JavaScript execution

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am having a most interesting problem in trying to figure out how to get JavaScript invoked conditionally when logging in on an application I am working on.  Basically, I only want a JavaScript popup message displayed if the user has successfully logged on.

In my xhtml page I have the following test JavaScript function, then later on I have a commandButton as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function hello() {
    alert("Hello from PrimeFaces calling JavaScript on the page");
  }
</script>

<-- Other html code -->

<p:commandButton id="login" value="Login" update="out" action="#{login.login}" styleClass="button"/>
```

Then in my bean I have the following code:

```
    public String login() {

     // Other code

     // return "login" on failure - go back to login.xhtml

     // On success do the following:
     RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
     context.execute("hello()");
     return "option" + optNum; // Go on to option?.xhtml where ? = 1, 2, or 3
}
```

For now my JavaScript function is only supposed to popup a test message on the screen, but if I can get this to work, I want something more useful to be displayed.

The idea is that if the login fails, the login page is displayed again with error messages, which works correctly.  If the login succceeds, the application navigates to the page number given by optNum.  This also works correctly.  However, before it navigates to the next page I want it to display the popup message, then on clicking "OK" in the JavaScript message, it is then supposed to navigate to that page.

Instead no popup is displayed and it goes straight to the required page, so it looks as if it navigates away from the page before it has the chance to execute the JavaScript.  This is confirmed if I replace

```
return "option" + optNum;
// by
return "";
```

at the end of the method, as the popup message is then displayed without it attempting to navigate to the next page, and stays on that page after clicking "OK".  However, for some reason which I do not understand why, sometimes it navigates to the required page when clicking the button a second time.

How do I get the code to execute the JavaScript before navigating away from the page? Putting the JavaScript on the pages it will navigate to or in resources does not work.

Does anybody know how to help me with this?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use just `<body onload="hello()">` on the user landing page?Or you could do it better with PrimeFaces [effect](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/effectMessages.jsf) component.

Comment: The JavaScript code is intended to read hidden values from the page, which are then displayed in the popup message. This part also works when I have an unconditional onclick="javascript_function()" on my commendButton.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong , your navigation doesn't happen on login but actually on the onclick of 'OK' button.

You can use p:daialog to display the JSF popups.

```
<p:commandButton id="login" value="Login" update="out" 
    action="#{login.login}" styleClass="button"/>

<p:dialog visible="#{login.loginSuccess}">
 <h:commandButton action="#{navigateToInbox}" value="ok" />
</p:dialog>
```

....

```
public String login() {

     // Other code

     // return "login" on failure - go back to login.xhtml

if(successfulLogin)
     loginSuccess = true;
}
```

See the showcase to understand how to use dialog with primefaces,

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf